# How to solve 'Failed to parse' problem to download a table using bigrquery

Tags: r, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I´m using R and `bigrquery` package on windows 10 to acces some data bases from `bigquery`. All works perfect but when a try to download a table with `bq_table_download` function, I obtain this error:

```
Error in bq_parse_files(schema_path, page_paths, n = page_info$n_rows,  : 
  Failed to parse
```

When I try to download some public data like this:

```
> df <- bq_table_download("publicdata.samples.natality", max_results = 35000)
Downloading 35,000 rows in 4 pages.
Error in bq_parse_files(schema_path, page_paths, n = page_info$n_rows,  : 
  Failed to parse 'C:\Users\...'
```

the same error mentioned above is populated.

Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 15063)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Colombia.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Colombia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Colombia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                     
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Colombia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bigrquery_1.2.0.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2       crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.1 R6_2.4.0        
 [5] jsonlite_1.6     DBI_1.0.0        pillar_1.4.0     httr_1.4.1      
 [9] rlang_0.3.4      rstudioapi_0.10  tools_3.6.0      bit64_0.9-7     
[13] glue_1.3.1       bit_1.1-14       compiler_3.6.0   pkgconfig_2.0.2 
[17] tibble_2.1.1
```

**How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: I am able to download the data! Have you authenticated oauth2? Specifically, have you performed this step?: `Is it OK to cache OAuth access credentials in the folder 'C:/Users/{your_username}/.R/gargle/gargle-oauth' between R sessions?`

Comment: Thank you for help. I discovered the problem, it's my proxy configuration, when I use a regular network all works but with the proxy don't work, I try with this:
```library(httr)
    set_config(
                use_proxy(url="http://myproxy", 
                          port=8080,
                          username =user,
                          password =psw)
              )
```
but still not working